# Keep the footer always under the off canvas navigation

Tags: css, html, navigation, push

I have a site that uses off canvas navigation. At a certain point the off canvas navigation will get too long and will start to overlap the footer. what can I do to push the footer down so there is no overlap?
I do not need a sticky footer. The footer just has to be below the navigation if there is a overlap.

Comment: Could you post your code?  It'll be easier to get help specific to your situation.

Comment: Please post an example code.. I think you have a css problem here

Comment: You can find the page [here](http://www.uitjesinarnhem.nl/contact2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this around your navigation:

```
<div style="padding-bottom: HEIGHT OF FOOTER">
   <!-- Navigation markup -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Jackson for the quick reply. 
This does work but the footer has a flexible height so there is not one number to give.